# Changing Thread Priority does not affect order of flow

Tags: c#, multithreading

A thread priority can be assigned 5 different priority level and it is supposed that a thread whose priority is above normal take precedence over a thread whose priority is below normal. However, it does not work even in the microsoft example(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority(v=vs.110).aspx). The results vary very rapidly. To be very specific, sometimes the count for abovenormal is highest and sometimes the count for belownormal is highest  I could not figure out why?

Here is the code from Microsoft docs.

```
{    
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Threading;
    using Timers = System.Timers;

    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {            
        class Test
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                PriorityTest priorityTest = new PriorityTest();

                Thread thread1 = new Thread(priorityTest.ThreadMethod);
                thread1.Name = "ThreadOne";
                Thread thread2 = new Thread(priorityTest.ThreadMethod);
                thread2.Name = "ThreadTwo";
                thread2.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
                Thread thread3 = new Thread(priorityTest.ThreadMethod);
                thread3.Name = "ThreadThree";
                thread3.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;

                thread1.Start();
                thread2.Start();
                thread3.Start();
                // Allow counting for 10 seconds.
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                priorityTest.LoopSwitch = false;
            }
        }

        class PriorityTest
        {
            static bool loopSwitch;
            [ThreadStatic] static long threadCount = 0;

            public PriorityTest()
            {
                loopSwitch = true;
            }        
            public bool LoopSwitch
            {
                set { loopSwitch = value; }
            }        
            public void ThreadMethod()
            {
                while (loopSwitch)
                {
                    threadCount++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-11} with {1,11} priority " +
                    "has a count = {2,13}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Priority.ToString(),
                    threadCount.ToString("N0"));
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Updating the Thread.Priority does not affect execution order or Processor affinity. It instructs the OS Process Scheduler to apply greater or lesser priority to assigning processor quantoms (timeslices) to the threads in the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results are likely biased because you have multiple CPUs on your computer. Therefore, the threads can all be scheduled for the whole duration of the run and the priority has no impact.

For instance, on my computer (8 cores), the result is:

> ThreadThree with AboveNormal priority has a count =   946,357,287
>
> ThreadTwo   with BelowNormal priority has a count =   949,074,221
>
> ThreadOne   with      Normal priority has a count =   946,164,189

This is remarkably close.

Now, if I change the affinity in the task manager for the process, and pin the application to a single core, the threads have to fight for the CPU, and now the priority makes a huge difference:

> ThreadThree with AboveNormal priority has a count = 1,541,675,169
>
> ThreadOne   with      Normal priority has a count =   584,725,723
>
> ThreadTwo   with BelowNormal priority has a count =    12,621,280